# ORDER BY artificial rows created using UNION

Tags: mysql

I've used a UNION to create an artificial row for "All Countries":

```
SELECT '0', 'all countries', '10000000000000' AS users
UNION
SELECT country_id, country_name, country_internet_users AS users
FROM countries
ORDER BY users DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The problem comes when I try to sort by country_internet_users.

MySQL doesn't seem to behave as expected. It doesn't sort at all. It wouldn't even run the query until I added the "AS users". But despite that it seems to just ignore the ORDER BY completely.

**How do I order by a column, when I've added an artificial row using a UNION?**

Comment: What data type is `country_internet_users` in `countries`?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek it's an int(10)

Comment: Then why are you using string here: `'10000000000000' AS users`?

Comment: I was just testing to see if it helped making it larger. It runs the same if I used 1000.

Comment: What happens if you use int and not string?

Comment: Is your intention to place the record `[0, all counties, 10000000000000]` as the _first_ record in your output?

Comment: Yes Tim, I was trying to use an artificial value so it would sort it to be at the top. And yes, I'm not the best at mySQL!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add a fourth column to each sub select which ranks the order in which each portion of the `UNION` appears.  In your case, you want the first portion of the `UNION` to appear on top as a sort of table header.  Then in the outer query, select only the three columns you really want to appear in your report.

```
SELECT t.country_id, t.country_name, t.users
FROM
(
    SELECT '0' AS country_id, 'all countries' AS country_name, 10000000000000 AS users, 1 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT country_id, country_name, country_internet_users AS users, 0 AS val
    FROM countries
) AS t
ORDER BY t.val DESC, t.users DESC
```

This approach is one way to guarantee that the first half of the `UNION` will appear on top (assuming that is what you want).  As @KubaWyrostek pointed out, if you can rely on the natural ordering of the ID values, then you don't need a subquery.

Comment: Is using subquery necessary here...? `ORDER BY` clause is applied to results of `UNION` operation anyway.

Comment: It has nothing to do with *natural ordering of the ID values*. Syntax is `(SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...) ORDER BY ...`. No need for subquery.

Comment: This seems to behave unexpectedly. It does put the all countries on the top but then orders the other rows in ascending order by internet users.

Comment: @AmyNeville Sorry...I didn't see that you want the students in descending order.  I added `DESC`.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek If she wants the top of the `UNION` query to appear first, and the ID is not sufficient to guarantee this ordering, then my answer is one way to achieve this.

Comment: Even if that is the case, you can still use additional `val` column *without* subquery. ;)

Comment: @Amy Ideally you might be able to do without my subquery, but if at some point the ID values get shuffled, your header row might find itself in the middle of the table.  Food for thought.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek No...because if we add a fourth computed column _without_ a subquery then by definition it must be in the `SELECT` clause, which means it would appear in the result set, and we don't want that.

Comment: In this case I don't think a subquery is too much of a problem because I only have 250 countries. But I can see how it would be a problem for other use cases. I'm also using a php application so I can just ignore the additional column if there was one.

Comment: What I miss here is that OP *probably* run into trouble because all `county_internet_users` were converted to strings and sorted as such.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how it was sorting. It seemed to put Romania at the top of the list. There was no logic to it.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Please stop commenting on my answer at this point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> MySQL doesn't seem to behave as expected. It doesn't sort at all. It wouldn't even run the query until I added the "AS users".

Run the first query individually and you'll see that, because you didn't alias the expressions, MySQL uses the values as the names of the columns it produces in the result set. That's it, the first query produces the columns named `0`, `all countries` and `10000000000000`. Of course MySQL cannot sort the rows by column `users` since there is no `users` column in the result set.

After you alias the third expression as `users`, the first query returns the columns `0`, `all countries` and `users` and now MySQL knows what column you want to use for sorting.

> But despite that it seems to just ignore the `ORDER BY` completely.

No, it doesn't ignore the `ORDER BY`. I cannot tell for sure but I think that, because the value you generate for column `users` is a string, `ORDER BY` uses string comparison for values of the column `users`, even the values extracted from the table are integers (or are they also strings?).

If the type of column `users`.`country_internet_users` is a number type, all you have to do is to use a number in the generated row:

```
SELECT '0', 'all countries', 10000000000000 AS users
# ... the rest of the query here
```

If the type of column `users`.`country_internet_users` is a string type then you have to options:

1. cast the value to integer in the query; this makes the query run very slow;
2. change the type of the column to a number type (this is how you should have created it in the first place):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE country
   MODIFY country_internet_users INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
   ```